# http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher, vuejs2, laravel-echo

I am trying to make my app app connect to pusher on a private channel.

But  I am getting the following error:

> pusher.js?b3eb:593 POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 404
>   (Not Found)

What maybe the cause of the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: You need to set up an HTTP server running on `localhost:8000` which can handle requests to `/broadcasting/auth`. The Pusher server libraries provide helper functions for handling these requests.

Comment: Have you resolved the isssue? I have both `BroadcastServiceProvider` classes uncommented in th `config/app`. Have cleared compiled services , config cache and route cache. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @The_ehT use public channel and use auth middleware on it

Comment: I had the same error and got stuck on it for about 2 hours.

Turns out it was my local host i set up a virtual host in my xammp vhosts file and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 115):

Look in config/app.php if you have uncommented

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,`

Comment: Saved my time. Thanks

Comment: MC laravel doc creator never mentioned this.

Comment: Saved my time too !

Answer (score 23):

There are two Service Providers with Same name but different namespace in config/app.php

```
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

So uncomment both of them. It will work.

Answer (score 20):

Hope your base url is wrong try to hardcore your base url like below

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
   authEndpoint : 'http://*******/public/broadcasting/auth',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '********',
    cluster: '***',
    encrypted: true
});
```

Answer (score 13):

**Complete These Steps**

**1)** In `config/app.php` uncomment this line-

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

**2)** If **above not work** and still you've got the error - then **I'm sure you are not logged in**. Just login to your account and check(because it's your private broadcast).

It'll solve your issue and since you can also pass additional auth parameters as your need in `app\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:admin']);
```

Comment: "Logged in" to? Laravel Auth system? What if I am using token based, JWT?

Answer (score 2):

UnComment this line in config/app.php :

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

and sure cache is clear with :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Done...

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing csrf_token() in your blade file?

You can add in the meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Check out your **BroadcastServiceProvider.php** and you should include your channel routes in the boot method.