# laravel websocket package is not connecting in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket, pusher

I am using laravel websocket package instead of pusher . I have followed all the steps. server is also running when I connect it it gives these errors.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/1234567/statistics
```

It is working fine with pusher but with this package it is creating issue

Comment: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/starting

Comment: When i connect package then i get this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704428/http-localhost8000-broadcasting-auth-404-not-found)

Comment: No, This all is steps are fine, as i mentioned it worked fine with pusher,  having issue when i use package

Comment: have you tried `new Echo({
   authEndpoint : '/broadcasting/auth',` .?

Comment: i think we use Echo for listening channel on front end. I am not currently using Echo