# XXXXX could not be authenticated to presence-online, Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm a newbie in Laravel. I have a problem when I tried to built a realtime message with Laravel & ReactJS, Socket.io , Redis
Errors when I start laravel-echo server

[image]

file laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
"authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"secureOptions": 67108864,
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
}
```

}

file channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('online', function ($user) {
return $user;
});
```

In client-side use ReactJS,
file index.js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});

window.Echo.join(`online`)
  .here((users) => {
    console.log(users)
  })
  .joining((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
  })
  .leaving((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
  });
```

Need some help ... Thanks so much !

Comment: Xin Chao em. When using Stack overflow, we need to get as much information as possible about the problem. Please tell us what you are trying to do and what is not working

Comment: Sorry because this is the first time I asked on Stack overflow, I'm trying to build a chat app by using laravel (back-end) and ReactJS (front-end), after learning on google I decided to choose socket.io and redis to do this. This is just the beginning when I want console.log out of users who are online on the system. But when running laravel-echo server, an error occurs "Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404" . 
If you have any questions, please ask more

Comment: in `config/app.php` there is a providers array, look for `// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` and make sure it is uncommented

Comment: yah I did that, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is redis running?

Comment: Yahh I've already started the redis server

Comment: My http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth is 404 not found, I think the problem is here and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704428/http-localhost8000-broadcasting-auth-404-not-found

Comment: See here for same issue

Comment: Thank you, let me see :<